# Project Structure for phone and tablet version

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

What is the correct project structure and gradle build variant settings for supporting a phone vs. tablet version of an app in Android Studio, if the two versions differ slightly in features and layout?

Yes, configuration qualifiers will work for resource folders, and can allow me to control my layout. However, I haven't found any official documentation on how to handle applications where the differences between tablet and phone versions is greater than just layout and resources. In my case, the MainActivity of the phone and tablet version, are very different. As one example, the phone has a drawer layout, whereas the tablet does not. however, much of the code between the phone and tablet version is the same.

What is the correct way to structure both my Android Studio project and gradle?

Comment: In this case I would go for two flavours or library with dependent projects